# Querying data between two dates from Firestore using LocalDate

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get orders between two chosen dates from Firestore but the problem is my query always returns 0 snapshots/documents.

I'm using `LocalDate` class because I have a JavaFX program and the date pickers are returning LocalDate as well. I know Firestore is using its Timestamp but im not sure how to properly convert LocalDate to Firestore Timestamp. Tried using java.sql.Timestamp, but it doesnt work. Any suggestions?

```
private static LocalDate dateFrom, dateTo;   
//...//

    Query query = null;
                if (dateTo == null) {
                    dateTo = LocalDate.now();

                    Timestamp timeTo = Timestamp.valueOf(dateTo.atStartOfDay());
                    Timestamp timeFrom = Timestamp.valueOf(dateFrom.atStartOfDay());
                    query = orderRef.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("orderTimestamp", timeTo).whereGreaterThan("orderTimestamp", timeFrom);
                } else if (dateTo.equals(dateFrom)) {
                    Timestamp timeFrom = Timestamp.valueOf(dateFrom.atStartOfDay());
                    query = orderRef.whereEqualTo("orderTimestamp", timeFrom);
                } else {
                    Timestamp timeTo = Timestamp.valueOf(dateTo.atStartOfDay());
                    Timestamp timeFrom = Timestamp.valueOf(dateFrom.atStartOfDay());
                    query = orderRef.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("orderTimestamp", timeTo).whereGreaterThan("orderTimestamp", timeFrom);
                }
```

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo http://prntscr.com/ozjfqd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I see in your database, your `orderTimestamp` property holds a [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp) value, which is correct. If you want to query the database using `whereLessThanOrEqualTo()` you can simply pass as the second argument a [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object. See, this class is apart of `java.util` package. There is no need to convert any date value to Timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Final solution was using `com.google.cloud.Timestamp.of(Date)` as an argument from this tutorial:

https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/google-cloud-firestore/understanding-date-in-firestore/

```
Instant instant = dateTo.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
                Date dateTo = Date.from(instant);
                Instant instant2 = dateFrom.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
                Date dateFrom = Date.from(instant2);
                query = orderRef.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("orderTimestamp", Timestamp.of(dateTo)).whereGreaterThan("orderTimestamp", Timestamp.of(dateFrom));
```